# PDO Driver installed, but php test say's it's not

Tags: php, pdo

Im trying to perform a simple dbcon test using dbo using php 5.4.13 + apache 2 under windows, but when i try it ( using the code bellow) it returns " could not find driver "

```
<?php
   try {
        $dbh = new PDO("pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=dbtst", "tstu", "tstp");
        echo 'Connected to database!!';
    } catch (PDOException $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
?>
```

So, i checked with `phpinfo();` and i it seens to be installed properly:

```
PHP Version 5.4.13

PDO
PDO support enabled
PDO drivers     pgsql

pdo_pgsql
PDO Driver for PostgreSQL   enabled
PostgreSQL(libpq) Version   9.2.3
Module version  1.0.2
Revision    $Id$
```

What could i be missing?

Comment: Is it a mysql database?

Comment: I only see the `pgsql` driver in your PDO drivers, not the `mysql` driver, which agrees with your error message.

Comment: You are listing the support for PostgreSQL, but you are connecting to a MySQL database.

Comment: Oh sorry, i will update the question :) its for postgresql. And i dont have any exception, only a blank page with "could not find driver " message.